# subject subscription is not working in angular 8..It seems the subject is not able to emit events

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I am trying to emit a subject while fetching data ,but the subject is not emitting any events

Even in component's `ngOnInit()` , I am not getting the log written inside subscription code.

in the service the code is

```
@Injectable()
export class RecipeService {

  recipesChanged = new Subject<Recipe[]>();


setRecipes(recipe: Recipe[]){
    console.log('setrecipes () is called');
    this.recipes=recipe;
    console.log('recipe list after set recipes ()-->'+recipe);
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes.slice());
}
```

Now in the component

```
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit , OnDestroy {
  recipes :Recipe []=[];
  subscription : Subscription;

  constructor(private recipeService : RecipeService  , 
    private router : Router ,private route : ActivatedRoute 
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnLINit is called of recipe-list')
    this.subscription = this.recipeService.recipesChanged
      .subscribe(
        (recipes: Recipe[]) => {
          this.recipes = recipes;
          console.log('recipe-list recipes are :' + recipes);
        }
      );
}
```

Comment: Note -i am calling setrecipes () from another service .Don't tell setRecipes () is not getting called.

Comment: what error are you facing??

Comment: And are you getting the log for setRecipes??, Also please try to put breakpoints using chrome devtools

Comment: i am not getting any error..If you see my code in the top,In the setRecipes() ,before calling the next() ,i am logging the data as i am getting the data using http client.I can see the data there just before emmiting it.but once i emit the data..then in ngOninIt() ,the log is also not getting printed.

Answer (score 3):

You won't get anything because there is no value emitted after the subscription in `ngOnInit` of your component. If you want to emit the current value to new subscribers, use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject

Comment: You can use subject also

Comment: i am fetching data from a service and In setRecipes() i can see those data in the log

Comment: yes mike ..i resloved this issue.This problem was releated to service injection.No where it was releated to sibject.

Comment: Could you add your solution here ?  I´m facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had too much RecipeService provider declaration, so more than on instance was active.
DS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).